# Pulling mySQL data and placing inside a variable in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying out something like below. I get to successfully display the `$Message` without the PHP script that you see in the middle.

```
$Message = "<table><tr><td>" <?php code A ?>"</td></tr></table>";
```

The **"Code A"** PHP script meant to pull some date from an SQL database and present inside a table as you would see.

I see with this code not working, the issue is the way I place the PHP script inside `$Message`.

Would like to know, first is this really possible to have a script running attempting to pull data from an mySQL database and assign the output to a variable and if so how should the script look like otherwise?

Here's the full code which represent **Code A**, if that helps in understanding the issue better.

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['savedata']))
{
echo 'some text message';
} 
else 
{

include ('dbconnect/index.php');

$SQLuserpw="SELECT * FROM USER WHERE EMAIL = '".htmlspecialchars($email)."'";
$user=mysqli_query($conn, $SQLuserpw) or die ('SQL Error');
$pendingRow=mysqli_num_rows($user);

if($pendingRow == '')
{ echo 'some text here';} else 
{

while ($reK = mysqli_fetch_array($user))
{
$wec = $reK['FNAME']; $wec2 = $reK['LNAME']; $wec3 = $reK['EMAIL'];
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr><td>First Name</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>'.$reK['FNAME'].'</td></tr>';
echo '<tr><td>Last Name</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>'.$reK['LNAME'].'</td></tr>';
echo '<tr><td>Email</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>'.$reK['EMAIL'].'</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
}
}
?>
```

**UPDATE**

Suggestion made by  @ADyson works.

Comment: "is this really possible to have a script running attempting to pull data from an mySQL database and assign the output to a variable". Yes. This is pretty much the most common thing people use PHP for :-)

Comment: but one question: is `$message` a PHP variable or a Javascript variable? I suspect Javascript but you don't make it clear, and the $ means it could be either.

Comment: That i'm aware :)  my question was is that possible to do inside a variable like what i've got here. $ message is a PHP variable

Comment: secondly, the output of the Code A snippet is a whole HTML table. It makes no sense to then put that within a `<td>`. Unless you are using tables for your page layout, in which case I must have time-travelled back to the year 2003 :-).

Comment: Well yes, I would not have the <table> echoed inside the snippet. So if I may re-direct you to the point, what's your view in embedding the snippet rightly inside $Message?

Comment: you would have to turn the output of Code A into a single concatenated string rather than a series of echo statements. echo will send the output direct to the browser, not into a variable. As it stands currently I suspect you'll get a runtime error anyway. Really perhaps the code to create this table should be a function which outputs a string. Then you can simply assign the result of the function to $Message.

Comment: Yup! make sense

Answer (score 0):

if the code piece you've shared is working, do it like that,

```
$message  =  '<table>';
$message .= '<tr><td>First Name</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>'.$reK['FNAME'].'</td></tr>';
$message .= '<tr><td>Last Name</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>'.$reK['LNAME'].'</td></tr>';
$message .= '<tr><td>Email</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>'.$reK['EMAIL'].'</td></tr>';
}
$message.= '</table>';
```

the use `$message` wherever you want.